# In R tranform data.frame to a standard tibble not comprising lists

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

How can I transform the below data.frame to a comparable/traditional tibble (i.e., not containing lists); and why is this behavior occurring/can it be avoided?

```
df_test <- structure(list(Dim1 = structure(list(0.1, 4, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                     NA_real_), .Names = c("one", "two", "adfae", NA, "")), Dim2 = structure(list(
                                       2, 5, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), .Names = c("one", "two", 
                                                                                       "adfae", NA, "")), Dim3 = structure(list(3, 6, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
                                                                                                                                NA_real_), .Names = c("one", "two", "adfae", NA, ""))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("one", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "two", "adfae", "NA.", "X"))
tbble_test <- as_tibble(df_test)
tibble_test
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Each of the column is a `list`,

```
str(df_test)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Dim1:List of 5
#  ..$ one  : num 0.1
#  ..$ two  : num 4
#  ..$ adfae: num NA
#  ..$ NA   : num NA
#  ..$      : num NA
# $ Dim2:List of 5
#  ..$ one  : num 2
#  ..$ two  : num 5
#  ..$ adfae: num NA
#  ..$ NA   : num NA
#  ..$      : num NA
# $ Dim3:List of 5
#  ..$ one  : num 3
#  ..$ two  : num 6
#  ..$ adfae: num NA
#  ..$ NA   : num NA
#  ..$      : num NA
```

we can first `unlist` and it should work

```
df_test[] <- lapply(df_test, unlist)
as_tibble(df_test)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df_test %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), unlist)) %>% 
     as_tibble
```